# how complex can an ASP.NET web page be?

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a Bridge game.

The main page, where you play the game, boast some 200 controls, like buttons that represents the 52 cards, 26 others for won / lost tricks, plenty of text fields... You name it, total some 200.

Actually its been already built and runs under Winforms model, but with the unavoidable question of implementing .NET 4.0 onto user's machine that must run Windows, and installing the software.

Hence I'm considering creating an ASP version (no PHP please, since I'm fluent in VB, and ignorant in C, Java, PHP and the likes).

Is that a "real" option or am I dreaming?

Will it run smoothly for users with a 2MB DSL connection?

Oh, by the way, no MVC please, I'm too old for that sort of sh...t :->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that many controls on an ASP.NET page your view state will be gigantic.  If you plan on only serving up a couple of games at once then it shouldn't be a problem but you have to actually start thinking about bandwidth with that large of a viewstate.  You would be better off with a DOM/jQuery type interface which displayed static images for the cards.  All interaction can be handled client side and validated with a server side call.

This might be the perfect opportunity to learn javascript :).  Remember each language you learn is another tool in your toolbox.  The engineer with the most tools usually wins :).

Answer (score 3):

Can it be done?  Sure.

The problem for you might be that to do it effectivly you will need to use HTML, CSS, Javascript and the like.

What most likely would be a good idea for you here would be to go the route of Silverlight.  It will give you a more rich UI experience and will allow you to code in VB entirely.

Comment: Well, the issue with Silverlight is that is asks the user to INSTALL Silverlight, which is yet another cumbersome stuff. I'd prefer to stick with whatever a browser can do out of the box!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see using ASP.BET directly as a good option here. To make it look smooth, you would have to use javascript heavily. I thing you would be better off with Flash.

Comment: Silverlight would probably be a better option than Flash, given the OP's language of choice (VB) and background (.NET).

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use pure **HTML/Javascript/CSS** you can create rich **Web UI's** by modifying the **Document's Object Model (DOM)**. With little knowledge of Javascript and the usage of some library like: [scriptaculus](http://script.aculo.us/), [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/), [jquery](http://jquery.com/), you can get rich interfaces. You should take a look at some of these libraries mainly **scriptaculus** because the set of animations it provides. Another javascript library made for game development is [gameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/).

Comment: +1 for the gameQuery link.  That was delicious, thank you :).